# POST values from dynamically created radio buttons to mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have some sets of radio buttons fetched from the database. Data tables are like -

```
    id  title    name     option1  option2  option3   
------  -------  -------  -------  -------  ----------
     1  Wi-Fi    wifi     Yes      No       (NULL)    
     4  Parking  parking  Yes      No       Optional
```

I have the following codes to fetch the data from the database.

```
$get_biz_meta_list = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM biz_meta_list")
<form class="form-horizontal" action="add-biz-meta.php" role="form" method="post"  >
    <?php
    while($biz_meta_list = mysqli_fetch_array($get_biz_meta_list,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="mid" value="<?php echo $biz_meta_list['id'];?>" />
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <label for="inputEmail1" class="col-md-3 control-label"><?php echo $biz_meta_list['title'];?></label>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" name=meta[<?php echo $biz_meta_list['id'];?>] value="<?php echo $biz_meta_list['option1'];?>"/><?php echo $biz_meta_list['option1'];?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" name=meta[<?php echo $biz_meta_list['id'];?>] value="<?php echo $biz_meta_list['option2'];?>"/><?php echo $biz_meta_list['option2'];?>
            </div>
            <?php 
            if($biz_meta_list['option3']!==null){
                ?>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <input type="radio" name=meta[<?php echo $biz_meta_list['id'];?>] value="<?php echo $biz_meta_list['option3'];?>"/><?php echo $biz_meta_list['option3'];?>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-6">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" name="savemeta" /> 
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Then after submitting it will post only selected fields to another table. That means if I select "`Yes`" for "`Wi-Fi`" then "`Title`" and "`Option1`" will be saved to the database. If Both "`Wi-Fi`" and "`parking`" are selected then both the values will be stored in separate row. I tried to catch the value like this-

```
if(isset($_POST['savemeta'])){

    foreach ($_POST['meta'] as $meta){
    $meta_name = get_meta_name($meta,$connect);

        echo $meta_name;
    }

}
```

*$get_meta_name is a custom function that will retrun the title.*

But it is showing Blank in the post echo. Please help me.

Comment: Did you try adding quotes to your `name` attribute?: `<input type="radio" name="meta[<?php echo $biz_meta_list['id'];?>]" value="<?php echo $biz_meta_list['option3'];?>"/>`

Comment: did you check what is returned in `$_POST['meta']` ?

Comment: No change on adding quotes. Printing the post array returns 
Array
`(
    [mid] => 4
    [meta] => Array
        (
            [1] => Yes
            [4] => No
        )

    [savemeta] => Save
)`

Comment: And printing `$_POST['meta']` returns `Array
(
    [1] => Yes
    [4] => No
)`

Which seems perfect.

Comment: where declaration of `get_meta_name`? what parameters types should be?

Comment: Here is the `get_meta_name` function `function get_meta_name($metaid,$connect){
 $get_meta_name = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM biz_meta_list WHERE id='$metaid'");
 $meta_name = mysqli_fetch_array($get_meta_name,MYSQL_BOTH);
 return $meta_name['name'];
 
}` 1st parameter is expected and 2nd one is mysqli connection link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss some quotes in the radio button name attribute. 
When you loop over $_POST['meta'], you lose the index which is the ID of your option. I don't know what you get_mena_name function does, but I don't know how it would return a 'name', because $meta just contains 'Yes' or 'No' values.

Correct your radio button quotes

```
name="meta[<?php echo $biz_meta_list['id'];?>]"
```

and your php like this:

```
foreach ($_POST['meta'] as $id=>$value){
    //do your stuff with the ID and its value
    $meta_name = get_meta_name($id,$connect);
    echo $meta_name;
}
```

Comment: even if she miss quotes `$_POST` is there with correct values

Comment: Ok, but indices get lost in the loop